# php: How to use only one database instance/connection

Tags: php

I'm currently building an API which should work with data from a database and then return them.

My database class can be found here: http://pastebin.com/PdDUeS3x

Now I have a User class which reads and writes data from the database.

Currently I use the following in every function:

```
public function doSomething() {
    $DB = Database:i();
    // Do something with $DB
}
```

Since I have a lot of these `doSomething()` functions in my user class I use often use `$DB = Database:i()`.

Does this for example then create three connections to the database when I run for example this code?

```
$User = new User();
$User->doSomething();
$User->doSomething();
$User->doSomething();
```

If so, should I add a class variable in my user class `$_DB = Database:i()` and in my functions access this variable instead?

Comment: Simple: actually instantiate it only once, and pass it to every class/object as constructor argument. → see **dependency injection.**

Comment: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: This seems not very elegant to me. And having checked some bigger php projects I saw no one handling it like that. But I couldn't figure out how they do it instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two different problems that you are describing: you want to only use one instance of the database class and another to manage your connections to MySQL.

So here's the short version:

- For the code in itself, you can either create the instance outside and pass the database object as an argument, or, less ideal, use a singleton
- For the database connections, you might want to configure your PDO::connect to use persistent connections (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Example #4 Persistent connections)

Comment: Thanks for the tipp of using persistent connections. That should speed up  my application a lot.

Comment: So you say I should create the database instance on the root of where my api gets called and then pass it to every object created that requires a database connection?
That looks not very nice in my eyes e.g. `$User = new User($userID, $DB)`

Comment: There are many ways of achieving that, nowadays people are mostly into handling such cases through dependency injection. If you want to do it very quick and dirty as a test, you can pass the db object to the User class, but that will make your life hard in the future, when you will have multiple "models" of sorts.

Comment: That's what I thought, too.  
Guess I'll stick with creating a variable in my user class for my DB instance and then accessing this in my functions.  
But I'm thankful for any other/better solutions.